# Can I replace an HP dv7's keyboard without voiding the warranty?

Tags: laptop, keyboard

It's a new one with one of those new Intel Processors.

According to its manual, http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c02842278.pdf

it appears that keyboard is not "end-user replaceable".

However, it appears that the main complex part is that it needs a dvd drive removal.

I wonder if the only reason it's not "end user replaceable" is that it's just too complex and takes time.

Is it safe to do it without voiding the warranty?

Comment: If its under warranty, get them to do it. Its probably simpler (and cheaper).

Answer (score 0):

It will void the warranty if you or the new keyboard causes damage to the notebook.

Why are you wanting to replace it?

Comment: It's defective and I want to avoid 10 days of no PC.

Comment: Its your risk, its really not hard to replace, just be very careful with the ribbon cable and where it attaches to the motherboard. Be sure to remove the battery and power cord when you do it.